# Load config.json with Angular2: Getting an error: DI Error at NoProviderError.ZoneAwareError

Tags: angular

According to some post, I wanted to load the config.json file in my angular2 app but got the error above in the frontend.

Here what I have done:

**app\app.module.ts**

```
import { ConfigService } from './service/config-service';


@NgModule({
  providers: [ 
    { provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: (config: ConfigService) => () => config.load(), deps: [ConfigService], multi: true }
 ]
})
```

**app\service\config-service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class ConfigService {
    private _config: Object;

    constructor(private http: Http) {
        console.log("Config Created");
    }

    load() {
        // Get the Config
        return new Promise(function(fulfill, reject) {
            // Get the conf
            this.http.get('/app/config.json')  // path of your config.json file
            .map(res => res.json())
            .subscribe(config => {
              this._config = config;
              fulfill(true);
            });
        });
    }

    getCentralSystemServer() {
        return this._config["CentralSystemServer"];
    }
}
```

Let me know if you encountered the same kind of issue.

Thanks,
Serge.

Comment: Just a question, why do you return a promise on `load()` instead of an `Observable`?

Comment: Indeed, I could have used Observable but got this code in the meantime from another thread and used it right away :-). And also, I'm juggling between nodejs and angularjs also ;-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you did not configure your service under providers array

```
providers: [ ConfigService,////////////////change/////////////////////////////
    { provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: (config: ConfigService) => () => config.load(), deps: [ConfigService], multi: true }
 ]
```

Comment: But now it seems that the 'http' is not filled (undefined) like if it was not injected and fails when it is used in the load() method. Any idea?

Comment: Never mind, just got it! it's in the Premise method and 'this' is not valid in function :(